# Convert XLTM to Google Spreadsheet formula parse error

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula

I have a very old excel template which works fine on all latest office versions. Now I am trying to convert this excel template to Google Spreadsheet. I have completed almost 90% of the conversion except some formulas which are shoing parse error in Google Spreadsheet.

Excel Template is using a formula like `=IF(B182="","",VLOOKUP(B182,[1]!PRICE_AREA,2,FALSE))`. In this formula, I am not able to understand the range given in VLOOKUP formula.
Could someone help me to interpret this range notation which is `[1]!PRICE_AREA`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that the template has references to some other excel spreadsheet. When try to convert using Google Converter, it automatically stripped the path to the other excel file and put `[1]` text. Now I am using IMPORTRANGE formula in Google Spreadsheet to import the range value from other spreadsheet and it works fine.